# Проверка последовательных дат Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, дата

Есть массив дат - `{"2017-06-17", "2017-06-19", "2017-06-16", "2017-06-18"}`.

Как мне проверить что эти даты последовательные? тобишь что нет прерываний.

Comment: т.е. день за днем идет?

Comment: в цикле очевидно

Comment: @Nikita да. именно так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = ["2017-06-17", "2017-06-18", "2017-06-19", "2017-06-18"];
var arr2 = ["2017-06-17", "2017-06-18", "2017-06-19", "2017-06-20"];
var arr3 = ["2017-12-30", "2017-12-31", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-02"];
var arr4 = ["2017-12-30", "2017-11-31", "2017-12-30", "2018-01-02"];


function isDateSequence(arr) {
  var d1, d2 = "";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1  ; ++i) {
      d1 = new Date(arr[i]);
      d2 = new Date(arr[i + 1]);   
            
      // 86400000 - это +1 день
      if (d1.getTime() + 86400000 != d2.getTime())  {        
        return false;
      }
  }
  
  return true;
}  

console.log(isDateSequence(arr));
console.log("---------------");
console.log(isDateSequence(arr2));
console.log("---------------");
console.log(isDateSequence(arr3));
console.log("---------------");
console.log(isDateSequence(arr4));
```

Comment: это JS. У меня Java. Спасибо.

Comment: ой. мой мозг дополнил метку :D  ......ну, собственно, принцип не изменился)

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант *в лоб:*

```
private static boolean isSerial(String[] datesArray) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(datesArray[0]));
    for (int i=1; i<datesArray.length; i++) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        String currentDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        if (!currentDate.equals(datesArray[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```